# https setup with apache2

Tags: apache-2.2, https

I have a site called http://www.mysite.com/ configured in apache virtual hosting.

Is it possible to make it use https with free certificate(if required)

Please anyone give me step by step guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from your earlier questions you seem to use Ubuntu.

Read https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/httpd.html#https-configuration on how to configure Apache httpd for HTTPS in Ubuntu.