# https connection in LAMP(Ubuntu server)

Tags: ubuntu, https, lamp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [https setup with apache2](https://serverfault.com/questions/182452/https-setup-with-apache2)
>   [Tips for Securing a LAMP Server](https://serverfault.com/questions/212269/tips-for-securing-a-lamp-server)

How to configure lamp running in ubuntu server for "https" connection..?

I tried something from here.. 
http://www.dannytsang.co.uk/index.php/create-and-enable-ssl-on-ubuntu-lamp-server

in that configuring apache 2 server section it says i should configure for CaCert.pem file.. but i didn't get that file by the steps mentioned in it. i need help.. thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the help.Ubuntu.com documentation for setting up HTTPS on httpd: https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/httpd.html#https-configuration